# Git: find the original branch of feature branch

Tags: git, tagging

Currently using Azure DevOps repo.

We have 2 main branches: `develop` and `master`.

`develop` is for development work and feature branches are created from `develop`.

`master` is used for deploying to higher environments, mostly merged from `develop` and the occasional fixes.  Fixes in `master` will get merged back to `develop`.

I have built a tagging process for the above, with all commits to `develop` will be tagged prefixed with "RC" e.g. `RC20230101.0` etc.  Commits to `master` will be tagged with "V" tags e.g. `V20230101.0`.  Commits to `master` will come from a branch that is created from either an RC tag or a V tag, the latter is for fixes.

For clarity this is the process:

Step 1: a new feature branch (feat.1) is created from `develop`

Step 2: feat.1 branch is merged back to `develop` and a tag is created, `RC20230101.0`

Step 3: create a branch from the `RC20230101.0` tag, and merge it to the `master` branch. This will create a new V tag, `VC20230101.0`

Step 4: a fix is needed in the `master` branch, create a fix branch (fix 1) from the tag `VC20230101.0` and merge it back to `master`.  This will increment the V tag it was originally based on, the new tag will be `V20230101.1`

[image]

The question:

I'm trying to find out where the branch has been created from and use this information to create a new tag.

For example, if this merge to `master` is from a branch that has been created from a "V" tag then increment the latest V tag's patch number.  Or if it's coming from an RC tag then create a new V tag.

There doesn't seem to be a way to get this information.

git log, git tag can't provide this information.  Is there any other way?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to find the tags associated with the most-recent common ancestor of two branches?

Comment: If would be helpful is you could include a mock-up commit graph that illustrates the relationship between the input revisions and the output revision you're searching for

Comment: Can you clarify this "with all commits to develop will have tags"? If you merge 14 commits into `develop`, each of the 14 commits should get a tag, or just the merge commit on `develop`? What about when you merge `master` into `develop`?

Comment: @TTT, yes, if there are 14 commits then there will be 14 RC tags.  The merge to master will be based on one of those RC tags only.  From master to develop will create a new RC tag

Comment: As apparently there is no answer to this question, the way I dealt with this a 2-step process: 1. get the PR creator to add the text `V20` into their PR's title (this is fine as the PR is to fix the artifacts tagged with `V20` something.  2. use this command to find this in git log: `git log --tags --decorate=full --oneline -1 --all`  -- if this is true then increments the latest V tag